# Anyone port IJG JPEG code to C#?

Tags: c#, f#, jpeg, managed, ijg

Has anyone ported IJG JPEG code to C#?  Are there any purely-managed JPEG libraries with source available?  I don't much care about the license, as I just want to use it as a learning experience, not actually use it.  Performance isn't a huge issue either.

I realize the BCL has ways of reading and writing JPEG files, this is mostly to satisfy my curiosity, and have a new toy to play with.

An implementation in F# would be interesting also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [LibJpeg.NET](http://www.bitmiracle.com/libjpeg/) by Bit Miracle.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.  My google skills seem to be lacking today.

Answer (score 0):

How about use C++/CLI to wrapper a C++ library by using `cli:pure` compiling option. Should be straight forward.

Comment: Well, I really want a fully C# (or F#) solution.  It doesn't need to be fast.  I just want to use it as a learning experience.

I've read the IJG code before.  It's messy.  :)